# no big endian and little endian in string?

Tags: c

We know different byte ordering machines store the object in memory ordered from least significant byte to most, while other machines store them from most to least. e.g. a hexadecimal value of 0x01234567.

[image]

so if we write a C program that print each byte from the memory address, big endian and little endian machines produce different result.

But for strings, This same result would be obtained on any system using ASCII as its character code, independent of the byte ordering and word size conventions. As a consequence, text data is more platform-independent than binary data.

So my question is, why we differential big endian and little endian for binary data, we could make it the same as text data which is platform-independent. What's the point to make big endian and little endian machine just in binary data?

Comment: Because, for ASCII text, there is no ordering possible. Every value fits in one byte. One byte is always in its correct order.

Comment: No-one uses ASCII anymore (or rather: *no-one should use ASCII anymore*), UTF-8 is preferred (if not dominant), and UTF-8 (and UTF-16) are multi-byte encoding systems. Note that **UTF-16 is endian-sensitive** but UTF-8 is not (that's a legacy of UTF-16 having to work-around the design mistakes it inherited from UCS-2).

Comment: @pmg Don't forget UTF-32 too! :D (As for UTF-8, the BOM is unnecessary - we can blame Microsoft for why we have to put-up with BOMs in UTF-8).

Comment: @Dai: Unicode is heavily ASCII based! When you have a text in English language, its UTF-8, ASCII, and ISO-8859-1 encoding are identical. So English language speakers cannot use UTF-8 if they do not want to use ASCII! And UTF-16 and UTF-32 **are** endian-sensitive not because of Windows UCS-2 inheritance but because characters are represented by 16 or 32 bits values which are endian sensitive *by definition*. UTF-8 is not endian sensitive because it is a mere sequence of bytes.

Comment: @Dai: UTF-16 is not a multi-byte encoding. Each character is encoded in 1 or more 16bits values (`int16_t` or `uint16_t` C types). And 16 bits types are endian sensitive.

Comment: @Dai _"No-one uses ASCII anymore"_. Hi, my name is NoOne.

Comment: secondimage, ?tfel ot tthgir etirw segaugnal emos od yhW  --- Re-draw the pics with lowest address on the right and see the two endians are simply mirror images.  There is no inherit advantage either way.  Just conventions.

Comment: @SergeBallesta There is nothing in your first comment-reply that contradicts anything I've posted (and UCS-2 is not Windows-specific).

Comment: @SergeBallesta "UTF-16 is not a multi-byte encoding." - uhm... 99% of computers running today have octet-sized bytes, so 16-bit values are necessarily multi-byte values (i.e. 2 bytes). Also consider UTF-16 Surrogate Pairs (thus they require 4 octet bytes to represent them) - that's a textbook example of a multi-byte encoding system.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I know we're all being an unhealthy mixture of sarcastic and condescending in this thread (myself included!) - but I (sincerely) maintain that very few software programs written in the past 20 years are actually "true" 7-bit ASCII when they're either actually using `ISO/IEC 8859-1` (including `Windows-1252` and derivatives) or UTF-8. I feel it's inaccurate to describe ASCII-compatible encodings (like UTF-8 and `ISO 8859-1`) as just "ASCII".

Comment: @Dai Let's say you are designing a byte-wise logging module in an embedded system, planning to reuse it in as many platforms as possible (you have to mantain all of those). Well, you want it to be as much simple and general as possible.. and you will make sure to use just 7-bit ASCII charset (it is just an example).

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I wouldn't "make sure to use just 7-bit ASCII". I've actually done logging in embedded systems (ARM mostly, also SH-3) and I've been stung badly by encoding difficulties. I'd use a proven pre-existing UTF-8 library. The overhead of using such a library (compared to using only C11's built-in `char`/`char*` functionality) is minimal, especially on modern hardware (including modern embedded hardware - even the terrible-by-todays-standards SH-3 handles UTF-16 fine).

Comment: @Dai: What I mean when saying that UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding while UTF-16 is not is that for example the euro sign character (`€` or U+20AC) is represented in UTF-8 as the 3 8bits characters 0xe2, 0x82, 0xac (hence 3 bytes) **in that order**. In UTF16, it is represented as the short value 0x20ac. It indeed uses 2 bytes, but the order is given by the endianness.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Counter-example: `U+1F4A9` - which requires 4 bytes when encoded using UTF-16 - and indeed, it is byte-order-sensitive based on endianness. How can you say UTF-16 is not a multi-byte encoding system?

Comment: It's a hardware issue. For storing anything longer than a byte, you need, well, more than one byte. On big endian architectures the lower order bytes are stored in the lower addresses and on littlem endian architectures the low order bytes are stored in the higher adresses. There is no way around this. It's either big endian or little endian.

Comment: @Dai: In a previous comment I said that in UTF-16 *[a] character is encoded in 1 or more 16bits values*. And I am still affirmative that a 16 bits value is not a byte.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Colour me confused - but what are we disagreeing about again? :D

Answer (score 6):

Array elements are always addressed from low to high, regardless of endianness conventions.

ASCII and UTF-8 strings are arrays of `char`, which is not a multibyte type and is not affected by endianness conventions.

"Wide" strings, where each character is represented by `wchar_t` or another multibyte type, will be affected, but only for the individual elements, not the string as a whole.

Comment: Indexed not addressed. How indexes are "addressed" is implementation defined

Comment: @P__J__: Elements at higher indexes have higher addresses.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is, why we differential big endian and little endian for binary data, we could make it the same as text data which is platform-independent. What's the point to make big endian and little endian machine just in binary data?

In short: **we already do**: for example, a file format specification will dictate if a 32-bit integer should be serialized in big-endian or little-endian order. Similarly, network protocols will dictate the byte-order of multi-byte values (which is why `htons` is a thing).

However if we're only concerned with in-memory representation of binary data (and not serialized binary data) then it makes sense to only store values using the **fastest** representation - i.e. by using the byte-order natively preferred by the CPU and ISA. For x86 and x64 this is Little-Endian, but for ARM, MIPS, 68k, and so on - the preferred order is Big-endian <sub>(Though most non-x86 ISAs now support both big-endian and little-endian modes)</sub>.

> But for strings, This same result would be obtained on any system using ASCII as its character code, independent of the byte ordering and word size conventions. As a consequence, text data is more platform-independent than binary data.
>
> So my question is, why we differential big endian and little endian for binary data, we could make it the same as text data which is platform-independent.

In short:

- ASCII Strings are not integers.
- Integers are not ASCII strings.

You're basically asking why we don't represent integer numbers in Base-10 Big-Endian format: we don't because Base-10 is difficult for digital computers to work with (digital computers work in Base-2). The closest thing we have to what you're describing is [binary-coded-decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) and the reason computers today don't use this normally is because it's slow and inefficient (as only 4 bits are needed to represent a Base-10 value in Base-2 - you could "pack" two Base-10 values in a single byte but that can be slow because CPUs generally are fastest on word-sized (and at-least byte-sized) values - not nibble-sized (half-byte) sized-values - and actually this still doesn't solve the big-endian vs. little-endian problem (as BCD values could still be represented using either BE or LE order - and even `char`-based strings could be stored in reverse order without it affecting how they're processed!).

Comment: *`modern software does not use ASCII, it uses UTF-8 instead, and UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding.`* This statement is obviously wrong. C string characters are always CHAR_BITS wide.

Comment: @P__J__ I use the term "multi-byte encoding" to describe the fact that UTF-8 can require up to 4 bytes (i.e. multiple bytes) to represent a single code-point. Would you prefer I used the term "variable-byte-length encoding" instead?

Comment: he is asking about C strings. There are not multibyte chars in C.

Comment: @P__J__ I I interpreted the OP's question's reference to C-strings as an example - not that they were only asking about C in particular.

Comment: @P__J__, even obsolete C11 acknowledges the existence of multibyte characters and the fact that they may appear in ordinary C strings.  The specification does not mandate any particular details there, but certainly C has multibyte characters in that sense.  And that's before we get to C11 UTF-8 string literals and wide characters and strings.  Or multibyte integer character constants. I don't think "There are not multibyte chars in C" is a very tenable position.